# Sending mail from a script which is run by Crontab

Tags: linux, cron

```
#!/BIN/BASH
# To alert whenever lsof crosses 80%

maxlimit=32000
echo 'Max limit is ' $maxlimit
tlimit=$(bc <<< $maxlimit*0.8)
echo 'Treshold limit at 80% ' $tlimit
a=$(lsof | wc -l)
echo 'Current usage ' $a
if [ $(bc <<< "$a > $tlimit") -eq 1 ]
then
        echo 'lsof =' $a 'has exceeded 80% of maximum limit' | /usr/bin/Mail -s "ALERT!!!" "*****@cisco.com"
fi
```

---

```
* * * * * bash /root/vasanth/lsef/script.sh
```

In the above script, the output is to send a mail to the corresponding Mail ID .

When I run it manually it sends the mail.

But, when it is scheduled in cron, the mail is not being sent.

I cant understand what the problem is. How could I debug it?

Comment: Are you running the cronjob as root?

Comment: is that Capitalize Mail in `/usr/bin/Mail`  ?

Comment: @Archemar That's not an error.

Comment: is /usr/bin/Mail a binary ? not a shell script that call stuff in $PATH but not in cron's $PATH ?

Comment: `#!/BIN/BASH` should be `#!/bin/bash`. It won't matter in this specific case because you're explicitly using `bash` to run your script, but it will burn you later if you get into this bad habit.

Comment: How did you add this entry to your `crontab`? (If you edited a file, which one did you edit?)

Comment: Try `* * * * * /bin/bash /root/vasanth/lsef/script.sh`

Comment: does the script run at all? Does the `bc` test succeed? Maybe add a `touch /tmp/i_tried_to_send_Mail` ahead of the `echo ... Mail` command to ensure it's attempting to call Mail. Does the Mail program expect an environment variable to be set in order to succeed?

Answer (score 1):

**1.** First: use `#!/bin/bash` instead of `#!/BIN/BASH`

With `#!/BIN/BASH` if you run script like this:

```
bash script.sh
```

..everything work fine.

But if you execute:

```
./script.sh
```

..you gets an error:

```
-bash: ./script.sh: /BIN/BASH: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

**2.** Execute this command:

```
echo 'PATH='$PATH
```

add output to the beginning of the script.

**Example**:

```
# echo 'PATH='$PATH
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

Comment: Which path is it that may be undetermined? He's using an absolute path for `Mail`. It would be `lsof`, `wc`,  or `bc` that would not be found, but they usually live in `/usr/bin`... Would be very strange if that wasn't in `$PATH` (though he may have mangled it somewhere).

Answer (score 1):

The main problem with similar cron tasks is, that you can't easily debug them.

Typically, cron tasks should work silently *if there is no error*, but they should be very verbose in the case of any error.

Extending EgorVasilev's answer, you can easily turn on a "debug mode" in a bash script script by the

```
#!/bin/bash -x
exec 2>>/var/log/cron.log
```

commands. The first interprets your script by the `-x` flag, what means, you will get all executed command in the stderr.

And `exec 2>>/var/log/cron.log` is a command what *doesn't executes anything*, rather it redirects the stdandard error into a log file, in append mode. Essentially, the shell interpreter "re-executes" itself with the given redirections, *without even changing the script execution context*.